# There are 7 boys and 8 girls sitting in a row. In how many different ways can they sit if certain 3 girls always sit together?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

question There are 7 boys and 8 girls sitting in a row. In how many different ways can they sit if certain 3 girls always sit together? Do you to 15! and 3! then minus them.Im very confused how to get this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I cannot comment now but I will give you a hint. First create a three-girl seat, then the problem reduces to 7 boys and 6 girls sitting in a row. Then within that three-girl seat you have 3! ways of arranging the three girls.

Answer (score 0):

Think 3 girls as one girl.  Then we have 7 boys and 6.       (8-3+1) girls so 13 people are here. We know 13 people sit in 13! different ways. But don't forget we get three girls as one and they can sit in 3! different ways. It means those all people can sit in 13! * 3! different way

Comment: So i do 13! * 3! which equals 1037836800?

Comment: Yes you will do that